# laravel query with random records with pagination

Tags: arrays, laravel, random

I have Query like this

```
return Quiz::from('Quizzes as Q')->select('*')->inRandomOrder()->paginate('10');
```

But i dont receive unique record.

I want to unique and random or shuffle record to every page and every time page refresh.

Comment: what is Quiz? model or what? if model why still use `from`?

Comment: yes.. Quiz is model. Actually i have multiple table joins query so i am using from  @MuhammadDyasYaskur

Comment: Try adding seed ```return Quiz::from('Quizzes as Q')->select('*')->inRandomOrder("foobar")->paginate('10');```

Comment: @mohammad.kaab ... yes i will try this. it gives random record. but after page refresh again records was not shuffle. i want every time records shuffle.

Comment: It could be anything, When a value is passed as an argument, the value is treated as a seed value and as a result, a repeatable sequence of column values will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return Quiz::from('Quizzes as Q')->select('*')->paginate(10)->random(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to unique and random

Something like this?

```php
return Quiz::inRandomOrder()->distinct()->get();
```

or

```php
return Quiz::inRandomOrder()->get()->unique('name? or other column to want set unique');
```